# The number of ways in which 45000 can be expressed as product of 3 Co- primes?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The number of ways in which 45000 can be expressed as product of 3 Co- primes ?

Comment: Brute force will do the job. Try to look at the prime factorization and combine the primes into three groups, then see when co-primes appear...

Answer (score 3):

That slightly depends on whether you regard $1$ as coprime with itself, which would allow $(1,1,45000)$. Otherwise the distinct prime factors of $45000=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^4$ are $2,3,5$ and none of these can occur in more than one factor if those factors are to be coprime. So we can have each prime represented in separate factors,  $(8,9,625)$, or we can include two of the prime-power factors in one factor and take $1$ as a factor: $(1,72,625)$, and two more.

Comment: The ambiguity you're describing has more to do with whether using $1$ twice counts as supplying $3$ coprimes.  I don't think you'll find much difference of (informed) opinion on whether $1$ is coprime with itself :).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Not many, as $45,000$ has only $3$ prime divisors.

Answer (score 0):

$45000=2^3\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^4$

**Case 1**

$1, \text{(factor consisting one of } 2^3,3^2,5^4), \text{(last factor)}$

> Count: $\dbinom{3}{1}$

**Case 2**

$1, \text{(factor consisting two of } 2^3,3^2,5^4), \text{(last factor)}$

> Count: $\dbinom{3}{2}$

**Case 3**

$1, \text{(factor consisting all the three of } 2^3,3^2,5^4), \text{(last factor)}$

> Count: $\dbinom{3}{3}$

**Case 4**

$\text{(factor consisting one of } 2^3,3^2,5^4), \text{(factor consisting one of } 2^3,3^2,5^4), \text{(last factor)}$

> Count: $\dbinom{3}{2}$

Required count: $10$